# ValidateInput(false) still trigger the validation in IValidatableObject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-validation

I have a controller which I dont want to validate, when called upon.

My controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Delete(MyLINQClass model)
{
    // Do something
}
```

My model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyLINQClass MetaData))]
public partial class MyLINQClass : DefaultModel, IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
         // Do validation
    }
}
```

I do not want the validate to be triggered, and I thought adding `[ValidateInput(false)]` would help. But the `Validate()` is still triggered.

Im using ASP MVC 3 and .NET 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[ValidateInput(false)]` is not related to model validation. It disables ASP.NET validation for XSS characters in the request such as `<`, `>`, ... The validation is triggered by the default model binder when it tries to bind the `MyViewModel` parameters. If you don't want to perform validation, simply write another view model that the Delete action will take as parameter and which won't have any `Validate` method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess I could have made another view model, but the problem is that `MyViewModel` is extending a LINQ class. So if I make a new view model I would still include `MyViewModel`.

Comment: @Martin, view models should not extend any domain entities such as LINQ classes. They should be independent and specifically tied to the requirements of given views. For example in your case you have different validation logic, so different view models makes sense. It is good practice to have your controller actions take and pass only view models from and to views, not any domain entities.

Comment: Okay, I see your logic there. I will try to make some changes.